# Почему у меня не работает код мне исправить ошибку TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str? Python

Tags: python

Вот код:

```
game = [{
    'title': "Assassin's creed |",
    'rating': "8.4"
},{
    'title': "Assassin's creed ||",
    'rating': "9.7"
}]
```

Я хочу получить сразу два названия игры чтоб было вот так:

> Assassin's creed | Assassin's creed ||

Пишу вот это не работает

```
print(game[:]['title'])
```

Выдаёт вто эту ошибку

> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: Потому что индексами списка могут брать только числа, а не строки. А game[:] - список.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
games = [{
    'title': "Assassin's creed |",
    'rating': "8.4"
},{
    'title': "Assassin's creed ||",
    'rating': "9.7"
}]

result = ' '.join(game['title'] for game in games)
print(result)
```

Comment: Обратите внимание, что ваша переменная game была переименована в games

Comment: Спасибо тебе век не забуду

Comment: Примите пожалуйста ответ, если он вас устроил